# calling function twice in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

actually I'm new in html5 and tring to do something using canvas , the function that i create is drawing a short ray length start from point and end in point , the problem is when I duplicate the function to run twice in the same time it doesn't work correctly , where is the problem in my code ? 
first I create the canvas

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1120" height="700" style="margin:auto;border:1px solid #000000;position:relative;z-index: 10;">
    </canvas>
```

Then i  create call a function twice

```
var path1Number=0;
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var x = 185, y = 185;
        direction1(x,y , path1Number);
        direction1(x+91,y+91 , path1Number);
    }, false);
```

then i create a function that draw a path start from point to point

```
function direction1(x,y , path1Number){
        //draw canvas line
            var canvas1 = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
            var context = canvas1.getContext('2d');
            var x2 = x;
            var y2 = y;
            var ini_x = x;
            var ini_y = y;
            var done = false;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, y);
            if(x2<x+20 && !done){
                context.lineTo(x2, y2);
                context.closePath();
                context.strokeStyle = 'red';
                context.stroke();
                x2+=1;
                y2+=1;
            }else{
                done = true;
                x+=1;
                y+=1;
                if(x2 >= ini_x + 91){
                    if(x2 == x){
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        context.closePath();
                        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
                        path1Number+=1;
                        path1(x,y,path1Number);
                    }
                }else{
                    x2+=1;
                    y2+=1;
                }
                context.lineTo(x2, y2);
                context.closePath();
                context.strokeStyle = 'red';
                context.stroke();
            }
            },10);
    }
```

the problem happened when i call this function twice it doesn't work correctly so what is the reason ? Thanks .

Comment: please advice immediately ..

Comment: my problem is clear for you ?

Comment: each time you call that function your clearing the canvas. so only the last one should be drawn. You'll need to plan out the order of operations a bit, right now I see several times your clearing the canvas, and without a demo its hard to tell what the desired effect is.

Comment: what I want to do is drawing and short ray moving in a path with start point and end point and it will be more than one path , in any path i call function to draw the short ray in specific direction and then return back to the path function to take order which direction else is going to be drawn , i have 4 directions functions that will draw around diamond shape .

Comment: the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/michaelraouf/ngSUu/9/